# Why can't I pretend to be someone already connected to WiFi?

Tags: network, wifi

I mean, i know it's not possible because first there is *the handshake* but i'm not really 100% sure about what's happening here.

I just need clarification of why couldn't i just spoof my MAC adress to pretend that i am some PC already connected and doesn't need to enter password to WiFi. I know that i would need to know *some keys* but again, I'm not really sure which keys.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question a bit more, something like "How do devices remain authenticated on WiFi networks?".

Comment: which WIFI authentication protocol are you talking about?

Comment: Just as a little tidbit, a PC will store credentials to connect to WIFI. A MAC address would identify a PC as the same computer as far as the access point is concerned, but it would still need to associate and authenticate to that AP when the lease is up/the PC disconnects from the AP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asume you are talking about WPA2-PSK here - the protocol commonly used for WiFi at home or at a coffeeshop.

During the four-way handshake, when the connection is set up, both the client and the access point prove to each other that they know the Pre-Shared Key (PSK), that is "the WiFi password", without actually exchanging it. With the help of the PSK, a Pairwise Transient Key (PTK) is derived. This is a temporary symmetric encryption key that is used to encrypt all further communication between the client and the access point.

So why can't you impersonate a computer already on the network by spoofing your MAC address? Because you don't know the PTK. Everything the access points sends  will be total gibberish for you, since you can't decrypt it without the PTK. Likewise everything you send will be total gibberish for the access point, since you can't encrypt it without the PTK.

For more information on the four-way handshake, I recommend [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004#The_four-way_handshake).

Comment: So basically you can do it, but the info that you'll receive is encrypted and useless? In that way you can DOS the user's connection and block him from the network ?

Comment: I don't know if you could DOS a specific user that way.

Comment: You can actually start a deauth bomb when you're not a member of the network, which will knock devices off of the network while they're trying to perform the handshake again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so few different questions here wrapped up into one. I'll try to answer each of them.

> why couldn't i just spoof my MAC address to pretend that i am some PC already connected

So what you're asking essentially here is:

> How does a computer know about which MAC address to talk to?

Well, there is a protocol known as the ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) protocol that allows machines on the network to essentially announce who they are. i.e I am on 10.230.5.4 and my MAC is EF45:3059:3202:24FF. Each of the nodes than maintain their own ARP table, which allows them to communicate. If something isn't in the ARP table, it will send out what is called a `WHOIS` request. i.e *Who the hell is 10.230.5.4?* The idea being that the correct computer responds with their MAC address.

> Why can't I do this without being connected to a Wifi network?

Well, think about what being part of a protected network means. People can not see what you're saying to one another because it is encrypted using some method, whether it's a PKI infrastructure or whatever. However, the common one for Wifi networks is to use a Pre-Shared Key (PSK).

When content is encrypted using a PSK, it not only protects against eavesdropping attacks (viewing content as it goes past) but it also provides *some* protection against Masquerade attacks. These types of attacks are where you pretend to be someone else. In the context of a PSK, the assumption is that the key has been kept secret and that anyone with that PSK can be trusted to be on the network.

Without the key (that you have been given or you've obtained through other means), you are unable to view content or pretend to be "part of the PSK club" (as my lecturer used to say), and if you're not part of the club, then no one is interested in what you've got to say. You would be talking Chinese in Italy. They wouldn't understand your attempts to pollute the ARP table and they would throw them away.